# MIPS - Printing a certain number of characters from a string

Tags: mips

If given a number, I want to print out the first 'x' number of letters from the alphabet. I've setup a counter to determine the number of iterations the loop goes through, but I do not know how to extract the correct number of letters from the alphabet string.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
.data
alphabet:
.space  28

msg1: .ascii " Please enter an integer from 1-26:"
msg2: .ascii "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
.text
.globl main

main:
li $v0, 5 # syscall for read_int
syscall
add $a0, $v0, $zero

li $t0, 0
li $t1, 26 # loop will start from zero and iterate to 26

loop:
la $t2, 0($a0)
beq $t0, $t2, end # once $t1 and $a0 are equal, loops stops
#li $t2, 1
#blt $t1, $t2, nomodify # do nothing if int less than 0
#li $t2, 26    
#bgt $t0, $t2, nomodify  # do nothing if int greater than 25
addi $t0, $t0, 1 #  add 1 to $t1
j loop # jump back to top
end:

# Here is where I want to take 'x' number of iterations and convert it to
# the string of 'x' letters

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Having all the characters in a string is unnecessary for this task. Characters are integers, so you can just start at `'a'` and count upwards:

```
# Assuming the loop count is in $t0
li $a0, 'a'            # start at character 'a'
print_chars:
    li $v0, 11
    syscall            # syscall 11 = print_character
    addiu $a0, $a0, 1  # set $a0 to the next character
    addiu $t0, $t0, -1
    bne $t0, $zero, print_chars
```